# I'm not sure what needs to be reshaped in my data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to use a LinearRegression() algorithm to predict the price of a house.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.drop(columns=['date', 'street', 'city', 'statezip', 'country'])

X = df.drop(columns=['price'])
y = df['price']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = lr.predict(X_test)
pred.reshape((-1, 1))
acc = lr.score(pred, y_test)
```

However, I keep on getting this error:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I've tried to reshape all the attributes in my data, but the only thing that I'm able to reshape is `pred`, and I still get the same error after doing that?

How should I fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pred.reshape((-1, 1))` is not an in-place operation.  When you have problems with a function or method like `reshape`, your first step should be to (re)read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on Documentation of [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score:`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score)

> score(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>
> > return R^2 score of self.predict(X) wrt. y.

You need to pass `X` as the first argument like below:

```
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
acc = lr.score(X_test, y_test)
print(acc)
```

Or You can use [`sklearn.metrics.r2_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn-metrics-r2-score):

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
acc = r2_score(y_test, pred)
print(acc)
```

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]])
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=42)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = lr.predict(X_test)
acc = lr.score(X_test, y_test)
print(acc)
# Or
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
acc = r2_score(y_test, pred)
print(acc)
```

Output:

```
0.8888888888888888
0.8888888888888888
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was just wondering why using X_test and y_test as arguments works even though we're trying to score the accuracy of the predictions.

Comment: @R_C, because `lr.score` by default call predict(X) and you don't need to pass `y_pred` to `lr.score`. you can read [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score) here.